# How to get element dropped on Nestable List

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, jquery-nestable

i'm making an relese access using Nestable List,
And when i drop the item from List1 to List2 i have to save on database, so how i identify what item was dropped on List2?

This is my code:

```
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3 class="droppTextCenter">Serviços Disponíveis</h3>
            <div class="dd" id="nestable">
                <script id="template" type="text/template7">
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        {{#each Services}}
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="{{Id}}">
                            <div class="dd-handle">
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    {{Descryption}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ol>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3 class="droppTextCenter">Serviços Liberados para o Usuário</h3>
            <div class="dd" id="nestable2">
                <script id="template2" type="text/template7">
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        {{#each ServicesReleased}}
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="{{Id}}">
                            <div class="dd-handle">
                                <div class="col-lg-9">
                                    {{Descryption}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ol>
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using template7 to make the List.

So i will make an ajax method on nestable onChange to save it in database.

```
$('#nestable').nestable({
    maxDepth: 1,
    group: 1
}).on('change', updateOutput);

// activate Nestable for list 2
$('#nestable2').nestable({
    maxDepth: 1,
    group: 1
}).on('change', updateOutput);
```

This one will be the replace for `updateOutput`.
When i move it, from List1 to List2 i have to save on database, but when i move from List2 to List1 i have to delete it from database.

```
function saveServicosLiberados() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/MeusNegociosAcessos/SaveServicosLiberados",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            Id: ????????
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');

            if (window.JSON) {
                output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));
            } else {
                output.val('É necessario estár com um nevegador com suporte à JSON.');
            }
        }
    });
}

function deleteServicosLiberados() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Delete",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            Id: ??????????
        },
        success: function (result) {
            var list = e.length ? e : $(e.target), output = list.data('output');

            if (window.JSON) {
                output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));
            } else {
                output.val('É necessario estár com um nevegador com suporte à JSON.');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So, how i take the Id from the item dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one to solve (If I did... You to tell me).

**FIRST** I putted the [***Template7***](http://idangero.us/template7/) difficulty aside.
I'm coding by hand in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/) here.
This HTML pre-processor syntax wasn't related to the question's real topic, anyway.

**The question is** how to save list item "movements" from a list to another, using the [Nestable plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable), wich is not maintained since august 2014, by the way.
**So I made two examples for you.**

[**One**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/KgbQvw?editors=1011) is showing where to hook an ajax request to ***save elements `id`'s dragged from or to*** the left list.
[**Second**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/dpwXNE?editors=1111) is showing where to hook ajax requests to ***save one or both lists*** on change.

I absolutely did not touched the plugin code...
It seems to be perfectly working.

Moreover, your question was about how to use a result from it.
So I started from [this GitHub example](http://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/) instead of your code.

I found where the relevant info could be picked up in order to save it to DB.

So have a look a both Pens.
And ask me if something is unclear.
;)

I've leaved all the relevant `console.log()` to help understand what's going on.



*Funny(?)* anecdote: I lost 3 hours today, waiting at GitHub to come back alive from the ***DDoS attack*** on **Dyn**, to post this answer. Shit happens! ;)